# Program accept word as i/p, checks for each single character letter in word consonant/vowel. Condition Print error message if input is not letter

Tags: java, arrays, loops, character

Output should be printing only once, but can't figure it out to get it out of loop once i find the VOWEL.

Go on by giving input 'a' once then 'aft'. You will know what i actually want...

```
package com.java;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class three {

    @SuppressWarnings("resource")

    public static void main(String args[])
    {

        Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter String");
        String a = s.next();
        char b[] = a.toCharArray();
        ///char c[] = {"a","e","i","o","u"};
        String str = "aeiouAEIOU"; 
        char[] c = str.toCharArray();
        //char[] charArray = str.toCharArray();


        if(a.matches(".*\\d+.*"))
        {
            System.out.println("WARNING!!!");
            System.out.println("please input only string");
        }
        else
        {
            for(int i=0;i<b.length;i++)
            {
                for(int j=0;j<c.length;j++)
                {
                    if(b[i]==c[j])
                        {
                                System.out.print(" VOWEL ");
                        }
                    else if(b[i]!=c[i])
                        {
                            System.out.print(" consonant ");
                        }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You forgot to actually ask a question.

Comment: output is not what it should be as per program. for input =atr output should be = VOWEL consonant consonant ..

Comment: What is "i/p"? It's not input, is it?

Comment: You problem is, that for input "a", you test "aeiouAEIOU", but after finding a you compare it to "eiouAEIOU" where every test fails. Similar for each other vowel.

Comment: i/p is termed here as input

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**The issue**

The problem is in your second for loop, you should not be printing vowel or consonant from within it. This inner loop is just there to decide if the character is a vowel or not, so you should update a boolean inside this loop and print out in the outer loop depending on the value of the boolean.

**code corrected**

Here is your code corrected (I changed variables names so it is easier to understand):

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
  String vowels = "aeiouAEIOU";
  char[] vowelsArray = vowels.toCharArray();

  Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
  System.out.println("Enter String");
  String inputString = s.next();
  char inputStringArray[] = inputString.toCharArray();

  if(inputString.matches(".*\\d+.*")) {
    System.out.println("WARNING!!!");
    System.out.println("please input only string");
  } else {
    for(int i=0;i<inputStringArray.length;i++) {
      // Declare a boolean to say if the character is a Vowel or not
      boolean isVowel = false;
      // Check the character and set the boolean value
      for(int j=0;j<vowelsArray.length;j++) {
        if(inputStringArray[i]==vowelsArray[j]) {
          isVowel = true;
          break;
        }
      }
      // Then do the printing here, in the input characters loop
      if(isVowel) {
        System.out.print(" VOWEL ");
      } else if(inputStringArray[i]!=vowelsArray[i]) {
        System.out.print(" consonant ");
      }
    }
  }
```

**Note regarding the regular expression**

You might prefer this regex if you only want accept letters.

```
if(!inputString.matches("[a-zA-Z]+"))
```

Your current regex, would accept `hey!`

**An other way to code it**

Here is an other way to do it:

- Using the `contains` method of the `List` object.
- Modified the regular expression test to only accept letters
- Lower casing the input string so our vowels array can be lower case only

See inline comments for explanations:

```
public static void main(String args[]) {

  // declare your vowels
  List<Character> vowelsList = Arrays.asList('a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u', 'y');

  // get the input string
  Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
  System.out.println("Enter String");
  String inputString = s.next();

  if(!inputString.matches("[a-zA-Z]+")) {
    System.out.println("WARNING!!!");
    System.out.println("please input only string");

  } else {
    // Transform your inputString to lower case 
    // (because we only have lower case in our vowels list)
    String lowerCaseInputString = inputString.toLowerCase();

    // Then for each character of the input string, 
    // check if it is in the vowels list or not
    for(char c : lowerCaseInputString.toCharArray()) {
      if(vowelsList.contains(c)) {
        System.out.print(" VOWEL ");
      } else {
        System.out.print(" consonant ");
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**And finally, a lambda version**

If you are using `Java 8` and are willing to use a `lambda`, you can replace the whole `else` block with a lambda

```
...
} else {
  inputString.toLowerCase().chars()
      .mapToObj(c -> vowelsList.contains((char) c) ? " VOWEL " : " consonant ")
      .forEach(System.out::print);
}
...
```

Comment: Got it!! Things work fine with first one of your answer but not if i use second one..Though got the code corrected ..Thumbs up!!!